# How to render component with two different states in two different elements in React?

Tags: reactjs

So I know how to render an array from state using map.
And here I have two arrays in a state of one component. I want to render each link with an image inside.The first image should be inside the first link etc.

How can I acomplish this with React?

```
  <a href={}>
      <img src={} />
   </a>

this.state = {

links: [
     'https://www.google.com', 
     'https://www.youtube.com', 
     'https://twitter.com/'
    ],

images: [
    'https://static.pexels.com/photos/380863/pexels-photo-380863.jpeg',
    'https://static.pexels.com/photos/350772/pexels-photo-350772.jpeg', 
    'https://static.pexels.com/photos/289506/pexels-photo-289506.jpeg'
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Not sure if I'm understanding this correctly, but wouldn't you be able to map through `this.state.links` and use the index to point to each element in `this.state.images`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
render() {
    const { links, images } = this.state;
    return links.map((href, i) => (
      <a href={href}>
          <img src={images[i]} />
      </a>
    ));
}
```

Make sure that you have the same number of links and images, otherwise you'd have an issue if you had more links than images.
I don't know what the rest of your code is, but it would probably make sense to change your data structure to be something like this:

```
const links = [
  {
    href: 'https://www.google.com',
    src: 'https://static.pexels.com/photos/380863/pexels-photo-380863.jpeg'
  },
  ...
];
```

Also, if that component role is only to display links, you should probably make it stateless like this:

```
function Link({ href, src }) {
  return (
    <a href={href}>
      <img src={src} />
    </a>
  );
}

function Links({ links }) {
  return links.map(link => <Link {...link} />);
}
```

Comment: If your data is closely related i would also go with the second approach of restructuring your state and map over the objects. It's cleaner and also easier to update the state and pass the data to other components. Also it seems that you should think about creating a stateless functional component that only takes a link and an image and renders that and keep state in the parent component. This way you have better separation of concerns.

Answer (score 0):

You could make an object in your state, where object's keys are the link and the values are image links and then use it like this:

```
    {Object
      .keys(this.props.links)
      .map(renderLink)}
```

Now you need renderLink function inside your component:

```
    renderLink(key) {
      const image = this.props.links[key];
      return (
        <a href={key}>
          <img src={image} />
        </a>
      );
    }
```

You also need to remember to bind this method to your component

```
    constructor() {
      super();
      this.renderLink = this.renderLink.bind(this);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the cleaner way is to do the same as the [zipObject](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#zipObject) function from [Lodash](https://lodash.com) library.

```js
const links = [
  'https://www.google.com', 
  'https://www.youtube.com', 
  'https://twitter.com/'
];

const images = [
  'https://static.pexels.com/photos/380863/pexels-photo-380863.jpeg',
  'https://static.pexels.com/photos/350772/pexels-photo-350772.jpeg', 
  'https://static.pexels.com/photos/289506/pexels-photo-289506.jpeg'
];

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    const {links, images} = props;
    
    this.state = {
      linksWithImage: _.zipObject(links, images),
    };
  }
  
  render() {
    const {linksWithImage} = this.state;
    
    return (
      <div>
        {_.map(linksWithImage, (image, link) => (
          <a href={link}>
            <img src={image} />
          </a>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App links={links} images={images} />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should restructure you state like @Elie Gnrd suggested. Use an array of objects that contains a pair of a link and an image:

```js
{
  href: 'https://www.google.com', 
  src: 'https://static.pexels.com/photos/380863/pexels-photo-380863.jpeg'
}
```

Then you can refactor your code like this:

```js
const Link = (link, img) => (
  <a href={link}>
    <img src={img} />
  </a>
);

class LinkList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {links: props.links};
  }

  render() {
    const {links} = this.props;

    return (
      {links.map(link => <Link  {...link} />)}
    );
  }
}
```

This way it will be easier to pass links somewhere else and to update the state. Side note: It is best practice to extract rendering logic like "how to render a single link with image" into a stateless functional component. This way your code will be easier to read, test and maintain.